# How to send email with pdf attachment using php?

Tags: php, email, pdf

Hi i am trying to send a mail with doc, docx and pdf attachment. i am getting email with doc and docx. but when i try to send mail with pdf attachment is it not working. Thus i am getting the error message 'The uploaded file is not supported file type'. I cannt find the error. Can anyone help me? My Code:

```
<?php 
    $to = $_POST["txtTo"];
    $subject = $_POST["txtSubject"];
    $from = $_POST["txtFormEmail"];
    $message = $_POST["txtDescription"];
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
    $headers .= "From: ".$from."<".$from.">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["txtFormEmail"]."";
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"])));
    ob_start();
    //Turn on output buffering 
    ?> --PHP-mixed-<?php  echo $random_hash; ?> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php  echo $random_hash; ?>" --PHP-alt-<?php  echo $random_hash; ?> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit --PHP-alt-<?php  echo $random_hash; ?> Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit <?php  echo $message; ?> --PHP-alt-<?php  echo $random_hash; ?>-- --PHP-mixed-<?php  echo $random_hash; ?> Content-Type: <?php  echo $_FILES["fileAttach"]["type"]; ?>; name="<?php  echo $strFilesName; ?>" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment <?php  echo $attachment; ?> --PHP-mixed-<?php  echo $random_hash; ?>-- <?php 
    $message = ob_get_clean();

    if ($_FILES["fileAttach"]["type"] == "application/pdf"|| $_FILES["fileAttach"]["type"]=="application/msword"||$_FILES["fileAttach"]["type"]==application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["size"] < 1024000){if ($_FILES["fileAttach"]["error"] > 0){ echo "Error:
    " . $_FILES["fileAttach"]["error"]."<br />";}else{$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}

echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";}else{echo ' File Size should be with in 1000 KB';} }else{echo 'The uploaded file is not supported file type.'; }?>
```

Comment: I don't know who has guts to edit your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Start using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), your life will be easier.**

Use example :

```
require_once('swift/lib/swift_required.php');

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setFrom(array($from))
    ->setTo(array($to))
    ->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get7BitEncoding())
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
    ->addPart(strip_tags($body), 'text/plain')
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($filename))
;
$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: My code working fine except for pdf file. can you please help me to edit my code?

Comment: I had a problem while placing my code in this website. So that it is looking untidy. Sorry for that. Anyway Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank You friend. I solved the problem. I changed content type from application/pdf to application/octet-stream. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Not terribly helpful if you don't want to/can't use swift

Comment: If you "can't" use it, then download it source, and view how it is done.

Answer (score 9):

Use Simple php mail function to send mail and dompdf to convert html to pdf will work fine.

```
        <?php 
        $content="<html>html content here</html>"      
        $html2pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();
        $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
        $to = "dheerajchouhan85@gmail.com";
        $from = "no-reply@email.com";
        $subject = "Thank you for your Contribution";
        $message = "<p>Your Message</p>";

        $separator = md5(time());
        $eol = PHP_EOL;
        $filename = "example.pdf";
        $pdfdoc = $html2pdf->Output('', 'S');
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
        $headers = "From: " . $from . $eol;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
  $body = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
  $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol; 
        $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
        $body .= $message . $eol;
        $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
        $body .= $attachment . $eol;
        $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
         ?>
```

Comment: +1 for the answer and noc2spam's comment. 
I don't get it, OPs ask about "how to send email with PHP's mail command" and many answers are like "don't use mail, use something easier"!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    //define the receiver of the email 
    $to = 'elangovan2men@gmail.com'; 

    //define the subject of the email 
    $subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 

    //create a boundary string. It must be unique 
    //so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 

    //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
    $headers = "From: test@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: test@gmail.com"; 

    //add boundary string and mime type specification 
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 

    //read the atachment file contents into a string,encode it with MIME base64,and split it into smaller chunks
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('testing.pdf'))); 
    //define the body of the message. 
    ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
    ?> 
    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    Hello World!!! 
    This is simple text email message. 

    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    <h2>Email Functionality</h2> 
    <p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: application/pdf; name="attachment.pdf"  
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
    Content-Disposition: attachment  

    <?php echo $attachment; ?> 
    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

    <?php 
    //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
    $message = ob_get_clean(); 
    //send the email 
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
    //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful to you.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
    <label>Your Name <input type="text" name="sender_name" /> </label> <br>
    <label>Your Email <input type="email" name="sender_email" /> </label> <br>
    <label>Subject <input type="text" name="subject" /> </label> <br>
    <label>Message <textarea name="message"></textarea> </label> <br>
    <label>Attachment <input type="file" name="my_file" /></label><br>
    <label><input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" /></label>
</form>

<?php 
echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);echo "</pre>"; //comment this line
echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);echo "</pre>"; //comment this line
if($_POST && isset($_FILES['my_file']))
{

    $from_email         = 'noreply@your_domain.com'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts
    $recipient_email    = 'your-emailid@gmail.com'; //recipient email (most cases it is your personal email)

    //Capture POST data from HTML form and Sanitize them, 
    $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["sender_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender name
    $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["sender_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender email used in "reply-to" header
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get subject from HTML form
    //$message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //message
    $message        = "Name : ".$sender_name."\nMessage : ".$_POST["message"]; //message

    //Get uploaded file data
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name        = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

    if($file_error > 0)
    {
        die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
    }
    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
        //headers
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

        //body plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

        //attachment file
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $encoded_content; 
    $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {       
        die('Thank you for your email');
    }else{
        die('Could not send mail!');  
    }
}
?>
```