# what is the code to send html code in pdf format

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui

In my case, I have a form in which a user enters all details and sends those details via mail in HTML format. It is working properly.

Now I want to convert the HTML to PDF, so that i can send the html as teh mail body and have the PDF File attatched.

Comment: tcpdf, mpdf, dompdf.... there's plenty of libraries out there that have been written for exactly this purpose

Comment: wkhtmltoPdf is a free and extremely easy to use for this purpose.

Comment: i want that filled details in PDF format, means user filled details online and send that detail to client, client get that detail in html format in his mail, so i want on that button click all that detail should convert in pdf and send as attatched file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to convert html to pdf for more info check this link

http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

after saving that pdf in folder during mail send you save to attach that pdf in to mail
for this check this link

[How to send email with pdf attachment using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396714/how-to-send-email-with-pdf-attachment-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

When you submit form, generate PDF file using any of PHP plugin like [**TCPDF**](http://www.tcpdf.org), then attach generated file in email header, So that any one can download.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [html2pdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/) project on sourceforge.