# email send with pdf attachment works but could not open that pdf and even after download also it was not opening

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am working with this below code but could not understand where I am doing something wrong?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// download fpdf class (http://fpdf.org)
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = "<h1>This is html template</h1>";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("certificate","landscape");
$dompdf->render();
$pdfoutput= $dompdf->output();
$subject = "Mail Out Certificate";
$message = '<h1>Certificate</h1>';
$uid = 1;
$filename = "certificate.pdf";

$from_name = "lifemadeeasy";
$from_mail = "example@gmail.com";
$replyto   = "example1@gmail.com";
$mailto    = "example2@gmail.com";
$header    = "From: " . $from_name . " <" . $from_mail . ">\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . "\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\n\n";
$emessage = "--" . $uid . "\n";
$emessage .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$emessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$emessage .= $message . "\n\n";
$emessage .= "--" . $uid . "\n";
$emessage .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"\n"; // use different content types here
$emessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$emessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"\n\n";
$emessage .= $pdfoutput . "\n\n";
$emessage .= "--" . $uid . "--";
mail($mailto, $subject, $emessage, $header);
echo "success";



?>
```

After execution of this code I am getting email with pdf attachment but pdf not opening. In that pdf I must show input coming form data. I tried with fpdf also where also the same problem coming.

Comment: Your hodgepodge MIME mail salad gleefully uses `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`. But it looks like you didn't actually honor that. Why not use a proper mail generation library?

Comment: which mail library should i use,please suggest me i am totally new to this pdf attachments thanks .

Comment: $html = "<h1>This is html template</h1>";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("certificate","landscape");
$dompdf->render();
$pdfoutput= $dompdf->output();
is there any problem with this peace of code?

Comment: Compare the duplicate, or see also: [How to send email with pdf attachment using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18396714) for simpler alternatives.