# FPDF email attachment and outlook

Tags: php, pdf-generation, attachment, email-attachments, fpdf

I am trying to work with FPDF and attach the resulting file to an email. I have seen this post [Email PDF Attachment with PHP Using FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353271/email-pdf-attachment-with-php-using-fpdf) and the answer given works when sending an email to my self and viewed in Thunderbird. Here is the example code given:

```
 <?php
 require('lib/fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'pt', array(500,233));
$pdf->AddFont('Georgiai','','georgiai.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('lib/fpdf/image.jpg',0,0,500);
$pdf->SetFont('georgiai','',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

// email stuff (change data below)
$to = "myemail@example.com"; 
$from = "me@example.com"; 
$subject = "send email with pdf attachment"; 
$message = "<p>Please see the attachment.</p>";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "test.pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

However, when sent and viewed in outlook (2007) it creates the message as an attachment aswell, is this to do with the code or outlook/

Any help appreciated.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

IMO it does not make sense to have *This is a MIME encoded message.* as the content of a part; usually such a sentence preceedes the first mime separator to inform any user of a mail reader without MIME capabilities what the following lines represent. In essence you have a mail with two text parts one plain text (*This is a MIME encoded message.*) and one html (*Please see the attachment.*) in a **multipart/mixed** container. If it was a **multipart/alternative** one, a mail reader would choose one of them to display, but this way a reader might be in doubt what to display.

Thus, I would propose shortening

```
$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
```

to

```
$body = "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;
```