# how to Genrate pdf file when fetching data in to database

Tags: php, mysql

how to Genrate pdf file when inserting Data into databas and Genrate pdf and also stored pdf into folder and also send mail to attachment for this pdf and send mail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're unlikely to get help with these three questions. Why not? First of all, it's best to ask one question in each post. Second, you haven't tried anything. You're more likely to get help if you show some code. Third, your first question is very broad.  Please read this and [edit] your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  (yeah, and nobody will mistake you for Mr. Gates, your picture notwithstanding.)

Comment: You can achieve that by writing code and then asking questions, not vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

The one that I know of as being best is the [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). FPDF is a PHP class which allows generating PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.

It is a great open-source solution for creating all sorts of PDF layouts.

To send email with the generated pdf you can check on this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353271/email-pdf-attachment-with-php-using-fpdf) question

[See FPDF tutorials](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php)
[And scripts](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/index.php)